# How to query DataGridView without Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

How to get the result of a query to `DataGrid` view without using Linq?.

In Linq I have a query to my dgv `dgvInfo` (the query gets the row index of the registry that contains the value in "colNombre" that is known in dgvInfo):

```
Dim dgvRow As DataGridViewRow = _
   (From row As DataGridViewRow In dgvInfo.Rows
    Where row.Cells("colNombre").Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(name.ToUpper())
    Select row).FirstOrDefault()

If Not dgvRow Is Nothing Then
   dgvRow.Selected = True
   dgvInfo.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvRow.Index
   dgvInfo.PerformLayout()
End If
```

The reason in not to use Linq is I have to use .NET 2 Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `Foreach`. C#:

```
DataGridViewRow row=null;
foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dgv.Rows)
    if(ConditionMatches(r))
    {
        row=r;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a for loop and checking the condition for each registry will do the trick

```
Dim dgvRow As DataGridViewRow = Nothing
For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvInfo.Rows
    If r.Cells("colNombre").Value.ToString().ToUpper() = name.ToUpper() Then
        dgvInfo.Rows(r.Index).Selected = True
        dgvInfo.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = r.Index               
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```